# Add fade effect to jquery rollover

Tags: jquery

I've got this little script that accomplishes a rollover by watching for images that contain an _off/_on suffix. Works great, but what I would like to do is tack on a fade function to polish it off. Sorry if this is really juvenile (feels like it) :/

I'd love to keep it dead simple like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.rollover").hover(
    function() { this.src = this.src.replace("_off", "_on");
    }, 
    function() { this.src = this.src.replace("_on", "_off");
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: My guess is you're better off using CSS transitions

Comment: Could you just add/remove classes that display or hide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){

    var a = '_off',
        b = '_on';

    $('img.rollover').on({
        'mouseover': function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(500, function() {
                $(this).prop('src', $(this).prop('src').replace(a, b)).fadeIn(500);
            });
        },
        'mouseout': function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(500, function() {
                $(this).prop('src', $(this).prop('src').replace(b, a)).fadeIn(500);
            });
        }
    });​
 });
```

[A sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AApNf/)

This should work well.

Comment: Thanks for this! Sorry for the noob question, but where would that go in my code above?

Comment: @cksum, yep. it would just go in your `$(document).ready(function(){` call, or, whatever shortcode representation you may be using.

Comment: Tried pasting it every which way I could think of, it just breaks my code (removes rollover altogether) :(

Comment: @cksum what version of jQuery are you using? jQuery's `.on()` requires version `1.7` or later. And, just so we're clear, you're fine to upgrade. JQuery has never(\*) removed any functions, they have only deprecated them. **\*** *nothing I can find, anyway*

Comment: Latest. 1.8.3. Do you mind just modifying your answer to incorporate it into my code? I need that much hand holding with this stuff.

Comment: @cksum - This is fully working. Just use this code as above. It works out of the box considering the circumstances you requested. Also, if you have an error in the console, show it to me here.

Comment: Awesome. Many thanks. It was actually a garbage character that was being copied on that last semi-colon. Works beautifully. Many thanks dude :)